# css3 - media query that addres only smarthphone landscape orientation

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have this css file for adding styles for mobile devices:

```
    /* responsive styles */
/* Extra Small */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container { width: auto; }
    .logo a, .logo a:hover { margin-left: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; background-position: 50% 0px; }
    .logo { margin-bottom: 20px; }
    .services a .row .service-container img { max-height: 60px; }
    .services a .row .service-container { height: 60px; margin-bottom: 0.23em; }
    .navbar.navbar-context.navbar-fixed-top .twentypx_marginbottom { margin-bottom: 0.24em; }
    .navbar-context .navbar-nav > li.navmenu-item > a { padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 30px; }
    .navbar.navbar-context.navbar-fixed-top .fifteenpx_marginleft { margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 15px; }
    .leftmenu, #hide-lm { display: none; }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar { border: 1px solid #4b4c4e; }
    .navbar-toggle { border: 1px solid #d0d1d3; }
    /*#context_main_logo a { margin: 0 auto; float: none;}*/
    .list-group-item.row .col-md-3 { padding-bottom: 0.77em; padding-right: 1.54em; float: left; }
    .list-group-item.row .col-md-3 > img { max-width: 100px; height: auto; }
    .list-group-item.row .col-md-9 { padding-right: 0; }
    .list-group-item.row { width: auto; }
    /* PAGINATION */
    .pagination-container .col-xs-12 { text-align: center; }
    .pagination { padding-left: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span { padding: 6px 10px; }
    .map-container { margin: 15px; width: auto; }
    #map-canvas {
        width: inherit;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px
    }
    #context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_oasis a:hover,
    #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_concon a:hover,
    #context_website_button_industry a, #context_website_button_industry a:hover { width: inherit; }

    /* INDUSTRY EVENTS TABLE */
    #industry-events-table table,  #industry-events-table thead,
    #industry-events-table tbody, #industry-events-table th,
    #industry-events-table td, #industry-events-table tr { display: block; }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #industry-events-table thead tr { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }
    #industry-events-table tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    #industry-events-table td { border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; position: relative; padding-left: 50%; white-space: normal; text-align:left; }
    #industry-events-table td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #industry-events-table td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
    #context_main_logo a img { max-width: 90%; height: auto; }
    #context_main_logo .navbar-toggle {
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding: 9px 13px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-context {
        min-height: 80px;
    }
    body.concon_style h2 {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    img.richtext-image.full-width {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* BACK TO TOP */
    .back-to-top { font-size: 11px; bottom: 1em; }
    /* PAGINATION */
    .pagination-container .col-xs-12 { text-align: center; }
    .pagination { padding-left: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }

    /* SERVICES */
    .services .child-pages { display: none; }
    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12 { margin-bottom: 0.23em; }
    body.services .services a .row .service-container .col-md-12 > span {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12 {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

     /* RESOURCES */
    body.resources .context_website_button_resources a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 133px;
        background-position: -10px -10px;
        margin-bottom: 0.23em;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    /* EVENTS */
    #context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_oasis a:hover {
        background-image: url("/static/contextis/images/context_website_button_oasis_off.jpg");
    }
    #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_concon a:hover  {
        background-image: url("/static/contextis/images/context_website_button_concon_off.jpg");
    }
    #context_website_button_industry a, #context_website_button_industry a:hover {
        background-image: url("/static/contextis/images/context_website_button_industry_on.jpg");
    }

    #context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_industry a,
    #context_website_button_oasis a:hover, #context_website_button_concon a:hover, #context_website_button_industry a:hover{
        width: 100%;
        height: 133px;
        background-position: -10px -125px;
        margin-bottom: 0.23em;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
}


/* Small */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .container { width: auto; }
    .services a .row .service-container img {
        max-height: 65px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item>a>img { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    footer #accrediation .row .logo a { margin: 0 auto;float: none; }
    .navbar-nav>li { width: 9.77777%}
    #leftmenu-content-href { display: none; }
    /*.leftmenu, #hide-lm { display: none; }*/
    /*.map-container { margin: 15px; width: auto; }*/
    .col-sm-9.centralcolumn img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
    #map-canvas {
        width: inherit;
        height: 300px;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top>.container>.clearboth.twentypx_marginbottom {
        margin-bottom: 1.54em;
    }
    #context_main_logo .col-xs-10 { padding-left: 8px; }
    img.richtext-image.full-width {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* RESOURCES */
    .context_website_button_resources img { width: 98%; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
    .context_website_button_resources.first { padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 15px;}
    .context_website_button_resources { padding-right: 7px; padding-left: 7px; }
    .context_website_button_resources.last { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 0px; }
}

/* Medium */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
    }
    .services a .row .service-container img {
        max-height: 65px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item>a>img { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    footer #accrediation .row .logo a { margin: 0 auto;float: none; }
    #leftmenu-content-href { display: none; }
    #context_main_logo .col-xs-10 { padding-left: 8px; }

    /* RESOURCES */
    .context_website_button_resources img { width: 98%; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
    .context_website_button_resources.first { padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 15px;}
    .context_website_button_resources { padding-right: 7px; padding-left: 7px; }
    .context_website_button_resources.last { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 0px; }
}

/* Large */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    footer #accrediation .col-md-3 {
        width: 23%;
    }
    #leftmenu-content-href { display: none; }
    #context_main_logo .col-xs-10 { padding-left: 8px; }

    body.services .row.services .child-pages .col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12 {
        min-height: 253px;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }

    /* RESOURCES */
    .context_website_button_resources a {
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .context_website_button_resources a:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    /* SERVICES */
    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12 {
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    body.services .services a .row .service-container img {
        max-height: 130px;
    }
    body.services .services .child-pages .links {
        padding-top: 30px;
        line-height: 2.0em;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

/* EXTRA STYLES OVERRIDES - START */

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media handheld and (min-width : 321px) {
    body.resources .context_website_button_resources a {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 0px -50px;
    }

    body.resources #blog-btn a {
        background-position: 0px -70px;
    }
    #context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_oasis a:hover {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 50% -245px;
    }

    #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_concon a:hover {
        background-size: 80%;
        background-position: 59% -182px;
        background-repeat: repeat
    }
    #context_website_button_industry a, #context_website_button_industry a:hover {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 50%;
    }

}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only handheld and (max-width : 320px) {

}

/* Tablets (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    /*#context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_industry a,*/
    /*#context_website_button_oasis a:hover, #context_website_button_concon a:hover, #context_website_button_industry a:hover{*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 133px;*/
    /*background-position: -10px -125px;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 0.23em;*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
    /*}*/
    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12, #context_website_button_industry a,
    #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_oasis a {
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    body.resources .context_website_button_resources a {
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-size: 103%;
    }

    body.resources #blog-btn a {
        background-position: 0px -11px;
    }
    #context_website_button_oasis {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    #context_website_button_concon {
        padding-right: 7px;
        padding-left: 7px;
    }
    #context_website_button_industry {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

}

/* Tablets (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    #context_website_button_industry a, #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_oasis a {
        background-position: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: 120%;
        height: 330px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    #context_website_button_oasis { padding-right: 2px; }
    #context_website_button_concon { padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; }
    #context_website_button_industry { padding-left: 2px; }

    body.resources .context_website_button_resources a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 330px;
        background-size: 110%;
        background-position: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 0.23em;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    body.services .row.services .col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12 { box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only handheld and (min-width : 321px) {
    body.resources .context_website_button_resources a {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 0px -50px;
    }

    body.resources #blog-btn a {
        background-position: 0px -70px;
    }
    #context_website_button_oasis a, #context_website_button_oasis a:hover {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 50% -245px;
    }

    #context_website_button_concon a, #context_website_button_concon a:hover {
        background-size: 80%;
        background-position: 59% -182px;
        background-repeat: repeat
    }
    #context_website_button_industry a, #context_website_button_industry a:hover {
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 50%;
    }

}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only handheld and (max-width : 320px) {

}

/* EXTRA STYLES OVERRIDES - END */
```

My problem is that the rules that I've added  just for portrait orientation of smarthphones are not recognized, probably due to the `handheld` keyword. If I cange it to `screen`, they will affect also bigger screens (tablets) and desktop. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not necessarily use handheld as media type.

Android and iOS ignore media="handheld".

Also most modern smart phone browsers simply ignore handheld style sheets.

Just use media queries targeting a screen with lower resolution and use pixel-ratio and pixel-density to be more specific targetting modern mobile devices.

**SMARTPHONES**

```
/*----- Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- Smartphones (landscape) ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- Smartphones (portrait) ----- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
```

**IPHONE 5**

```
/*----- iPhone 5 in portrait & landscape ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- iPhone 5 in landscape ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- iPhone 5 in portrait ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
```

**IPHONE 2G-4S**

```
/*----- iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- iPhone 2G-4S in landscape ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
/*----- iPhone 2G-4S in portrait ----- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Place Your Styles Here */
}
```

When targeting tablet you might consider using `and orientation(landscape){` but for mobile is not necessary, you can simply rely on the screen resolution.